# http static directories aren't being served

Tags: linux, http, web-applications, filesystems, go

I don't understand why my static resources aren't being served. Here is the code:

```
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", get_shows)
    http.HandleFunc("/get",  get_show_json)
    http.HandleFunc("/set", set_shows)
    http.Handle("/css/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./css")))
    http.Handle("/js/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./js")))
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

When I run the program, navigating to http://myhost.fake/css/ or to http://myhost.fake/css/main.css (these exists in the filesystem), I get a 404 error. The same is true if I replace "./css" with the full path to the directory. Ditto for the js static directory. My other handlers work fine. I am on a linux. Thanks!

Comment: Why is this filed under "linux"? How can I make "Go" the main category of the question?

Comment: I think perhaps right now it's looking for `/full/path/to/css/css/`. Try giving the `http.Dir()` the parent directory of the `js` and `css` directories.

Comment: @thesystem, you're right. This isn't obvious to me from the documentation at all, though.

Comment: @Jeremy - this is why the answer including `http.StripPrefix` is correct.  And I agree -- it's not obvious in the docs.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your handler path (`/css/`) is passed to the FileServer handler plus the file after the prefix.
That means when you visit http://myhost.fake/css/test.css your FileServer is trying to find the file `./css/css/test.css`.

The http package provides the function [`StripPrefix`](http://godoc.org/net/http#StripPrefix) to strip the `/css/` prefix.

This should do it:

```
http.Handle("/css/", http.StripPrefix("/css/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("css"))))
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm now using `http.Handle("/css/", http.FileServer(http.Dir(".")))` which is working as expected.

Comment: Also, bear in mind that a relative path is resolved with respect to the directory from which your server static executable is run (not relative to that binary). To debug a problem, I've found it useful to toss `log.Printf(os.Getwd())` in there or list the files.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot verify it now, but IIRC: `s/"./css"/"css"/`; `s/"./js"/"js"/`.

EDIT: Now that I can finally check the sources: This is what I did and what works for me:

```
http.Handle("/scripts/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("")))
http.Handle("/images/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("")))
```

All images in `./images/*.{gif,png,...}` get served properly. The same story about scripts.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the issue.

Comment: Damned!. I solved exactly the same issue just days ago and I cannot recall the correct answer :-(

Comment: @Jeremy: Just for your reference, I've updated the answer to the working solution.